# How to save the Instance State in Android applications developed with Titanium?

Tags: android, titanium, android-camera, appcelerator, titanium-mobile

I'm working with Titanium 3.1 and developing for Android 3.0 and greater.

My app has a view that when clicked asks you if you want to take a picture or select an image from gallery. When I choose to take a picture from the camera, the camera shows with no problem and I can take the picture, the problem is that after I take the picture and choose to use it, my app resume from the beginning, not returning to the previous state it was showing before choosing to take a picture.

When I checked logcat I saw this line:

```
I/TiRootActivity(24120): (main) [0,0] checkpoint, on root activity create, savedInstanceState: null
```

It seems the state of my app is not being saved, but I don't know why. I'll be honest, this is my first time working on an app that goes to the camera app, takes a picture and returns to the app. Previously I've worked with Intents in Titanium and I've been able to return to the correct state of my app after exiting the application that was opened with the Intent using the back button.

This is the code I use to open the camera:

```
var globalBabyPicture = Titanium.UI.createImageView({   
    image:imagesPath + "kinedu_0027_ic_camara.png",
    width:75,   
});

var photoOptionsViewFromCamera = Ti.UI.createView({
    width:Ti.Platform.displayCaps.platformWidth,
    height:44, 
    left:0, 
    top:1*44,
    backgroundColor:"transparent"
});

var photoOptionsViewFromCameraLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:"from camera", 
    font:{fontSize:14, fontFamily:"Arial Rounded MT Bold"}, 
    color:"#368cd6"
});

photoOptionsViewFromCamera.add(photoOptionsViewFromCameraLabel);

photoOptionsViewFromCamera.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
    var animateTouchStart = Ti.UI.createAnimation({backgroundColor:"#AFD1DE", duration:150});
    photoOptionsViewFromCamera.animate(animateTouchStart);

});

//********* this is the code that triggers the camera to take the picture
photoOptionsViewFromCamera.addEventListener("touchend", function(e){
    var animateTouchEnd = Ti.UI.createAnimation({backgroundColor:"transparent", duration:150});
    photoOptionsViewFromCamera.animate(animateTouchEnd);

    animateTouchEnd.addEventListener("complete", function(e){
        Ti.Media.showCamera({
            success : function(event) {

                var tmp = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, ('baby_temp.png'));
                    tmp.write(event.media);
                    var blob = tmp.read();

                    Ti.App.fireEvent("changePicture");

                },
            cancel : function() {
            },
            error : function(error) {
                var message;
                if (error.code == Ti.Media.NO_CAMERA) {
                    message = 'Device does not have camera capabilities';
                } else {
                    message = 'Unexpected error: ' + error.code;
                }

                Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                    title : 'Camera',
                    message : message
                }).show();
            },
            saveToPhotoGallery : false,
            allowEditing : true,
            mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_PHOTO]
        });     
    });
});


Ti.App.addEventListener("changePicture", function(e){
    var tmp = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.tempDirectory, ('baby_temp.png'));
    var blob = tmp.read();

    var animationChange = Ti.UI.createAnimation({opacity:0, duration:200});

    babyImage.animate(animationChange);

    var animationChangeCompleted = Ti.UI.createAnimation({opacity:1, duration:200});

    animationChange.addEventListener("complete", function(e){
        babyImage.setWidth(100);
        var image = blob.imageAsThumbnail(150);                         
        babyImage.setImage(image);              
        babyImage.animate(animationChangeCompleted);
    });             
});
```

I've checked and the success callback is never made, I think it's because the application resumes from the beginning, showing the application splash screen.

How can I ensure that after taking the picture, the application returns to the previous view without resuming the application from the beginning?

Comment: IF your app is showing splash it may be a crash, and you are confusing it with resuming the application from the beginning.
I would suggest checking the logcat from adb also along with Titanium console and paste the logs here.

Answer (score 0):

I think `allowEditing` should be `allowImageEditing`